# Access violation while calling a DLL function

Tags: dll, delphi-2010

I have the next unction on a DLL:

```
function PedirContraseña() : string;
var
clave, claveCodificada : string;
begin


clave := InputBox('Autenticación', 'Introduzca la clave de acceso', '');
claveCodificada := SHA256Hash(clave);
Result := claveCodificada;

end;

exports PedirContraseña;
```

It asks to the user for a password, then it applies the SHA256 hash and returns the result of this hash.

On the main application I have the following call:

```
function PedirContraseña() : string; external 'seguridad.dll';



procedure Tmenubodega.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : string;
begin
  inherited;
    s := PedirContraseña;
    ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

- The first time I click the button it works fine.
- The second time it still works.
- From now, each 2 clicks it will show an Access Violation exception on the dll (1 time does, next time doesn't, next time does, next time doesn't...)

I'm confused. What can I do?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Are you using a shared memory manager?

Comment: No (at least, not consciously)

Comment: Well, you need to be if you want to return a string that was allocated in one model to another module which destroys it. But in this case since you are in control of both modules, and are using Delphi specific types, why aren't you using packages?

Comment: I never programmed a package, so I didn't think about it. About the DLL; I've added the Sharemem unit and it works fine know (this happens to me because not reading the autogenerated comments -_- )

Thank's